# "a/the key" or just "key"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

I want to indicate that *agricultural analysis* is key but not the only one key, so I don't use *the key*. Is it possible to use **key** without (a/the)? Grammarly indicates it is necessary to use one of them. However, **a key** doesn't sound as strong as **key** to me.

I think *agricultural analysis* is **key** to create urban sustainability, so I want to deepen my knowledge of it by studying the bachelor in sciences.

Comment: Using "key" as an adjective (and therefore without an article) is correct, but I think it requires a change to the subsequent phrase: "agricultural analysis is key **in creating** urban sustainability."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use *key* alone here, as an adjective. I would say *key to creating...*. [**Edit:** or *in creating*, as the commenter above suggests.]

When used as an adjective, it does indeed have the meaning you suggest: very important, but not the **only** important thing.

*A key* is strange and not really used in this context. *The key to creating...* suggests that it is the **most important** thing.

Answer (score 0):

> agricultural analysis is the key *(noun)* in creating urban sustainability

> agricultural analysis is a key *(noun)* in creating urban sustainability

> agricultural analysis is a key *(adjective)* component/element/factor in creating urban sustainability

> agricultural analysis is key *(adjective)* in creating urban sustainability

The last sentence is correct since *key* is both a noun and adjective. If there were no adjectival form of the word, you would have to put an article before it.

That said, I don't think it's a nice way to put it given that there is a plenty of great words to define it.

```
essential
important
vital
fundamental
necessary 
crucial
fundamental
imperative
indispensable
main
integral
part and parcel
```

to name a few.